# Configure GSA to crawl content

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

My website is say www.abc.com and there is a specific url pattern which contains both secure and non secure content. For example www.abc.com/foo/xxx serves secured/open content depending on the content.

How can I tell GSA to use secure crawl for the secure content? I know this is simple is the specific url always seved secured content. I have read google's support site [here](http://goo.gl/qgI8Gs), but how will GSA know that some urls are secured content? I can't list all the urls in GSA admin console because there are more than 10K of such unique urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that some urls in your website are secured and rest are public urls.
And you wanted to tell GSA to use Controlled-Access Content crawl only for the secured urls.
If this is the case, then you have to move all the secured content to some common pattern Ex: www.abc.com/secured/xxx and crawl that pattern using Controlled-Access Content crawling.
If that is not a feasible solution, then add some meta tag to the web pages 
(For open pages- add viewers= public, For Secured pages- add viewers=secured) and crawl your whole site using Controlled-Access Content crawl and make all urls public using GSA configuration.
For serving the results, do the authentication in your application and query GSA with appropriate value in viewers requiredfields parameter.

Comment: Thanks! When GSA hits a secured content url, then it is redirected to a login page. So GSA can't read the metadata until it goes past the login page. How can I handle such situations?

Comment: Is your website SSO protected? If so ,then you have to use forms authentication configuration in gsa.Try crawling your secured page after setting up forms authentication.

Comment: You have to configure gsa according to your website authentication method.ex:if it is SSO protected,you have to use forms authentication in gsa.if you configure it appropriately, then gsa will take care of indexing secured pages by providing credentials to the login page.

Comment: Thanks @Mohan, your answer helped me solve the porblem.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, we need to mark the secure URLs as public in order to expose them in the search results for anonymous users. We need to check the "Make public" check box next to the url.

Comment: Welcome.:) Yes, we have to mark "Make Public" to expose secured documents in normal results. But be careful while doingso bcoz public users can see your secured contents in the search results unless you use metadata filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question (and not your problem) is:

The GSA will determine if the content is secure or not based on the http response by the web server.  If your content responds with a 401 or 301/302 then the GSA will assume this content is secure.

Public content is determine if the content responds with 200.